# Why isn't an Exception Caught when Thrown Out of Task.WhenAll?

Tags: c#, exception, async-await, try-catch, task

The issue I'm having is that the an exception (marked below) is not being caught when thrown into the  catch statement surrounding `Task.WhenAll`. I'm not sure why this exception is ballooning up to the call stack.

I read the following [article](https://thesharperdev.com/csharps-whenall-and-exception-handling/) that states a try/catch wrapping an awaited Task.WhenAll will catch the first exception thrown out of it, but that doesn't seem to be the case for me....

I have the following code snippet below (you can copy and paste it and just hit 'Run') to reproduce (.netcoreapp2.1).

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;


namespace TestProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        private static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var token = tokenSource.Token;
            var thread = new Thread(() => CancelToken(tokenSource));
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
            var ourTask = SpinUntilCancelled(token);
            try
            {
                await Task.WhenAll(ourTask);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) // NOT CATCHING AND PRINTING!
            { Console.WriteLine($"{ex}"); }
        }

        private static void CancelToken(CancellationTokenSource obj)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            obj.Cancel();
            obj.Dispose();
            return;
        }

        private static Task SpinUntilCancelled(CancellationToken cancellation)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
                        throw new ApplicationException("Token cancelled");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Text {++i}");
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cancelled!");
                    cancellation.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, my breakpoint is not being hit.

[image]

Comment: There is no asynchronous code in your sample and code *never* gets to `.WhenAll` or inside `try`/`cathc` block... Are you missing `await Task.Delay()` somewhere? Overall question looks like just typo...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov How is that possible when it gets to SpinUntilCancelled, and prints Text1, Text2, Text3... before the seperate thread calls Cancel on the TokenSource

Comment: Unfriendly or unkind comment: @TeeZadAwk did you try to step through the code? You blaming `try { await Task.WhenAll(ourTask); } ...` code for not working when it is *not even called*...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: you're right, sorry...the method doesn't need a return statement because it cannot ever complete, due to the `while (true)`. compiler doesn't even complain about it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the `while (true)` and the lack of a `break` or `return` statement, the `SpinUntilCancelled` method never produces a value, so its return type is irrelevant. To make it produce an actual `Task` that you can later `await`, you should give it a proper asynchronous implementation, like this:

```
private static async Task SpinUntilCancelled(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationToken);
        Console.WriteLine($"Text {++i}");
    }
}
```

As a side note, if you want to get an instant notification when the `CancellationTokenSource` is canceled, you can [`Register`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.register) a callback to its `Token` like this:

```
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
tokenSource.Token.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("Token canceled"));
```

Comment: What if I add return Task.CompletedTask at the end (after the while loop? I don't understand why my current implementation does not produce a Task. Your implemention doesn't return a task either.

Comment: @TeeZadAwk adding `return Task.CompletedTask` after the while `loop` would make no difference, because the loop has no way out to reach that statement. Because of this, the proper return type of the method would be `void`, not `Task`. Your method currently has an asynchronous contract, but not an asynchronous implementation. It says to the callers: *"Hey! call me and I'll give you back a Task that represents the final completion of the asynchronous operation"*. But it doesn't fulfill this promise. It blocks the caller forever, never returning anything.

Comment: @TeeZadAwk my suggestion is implemented with [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/). The [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) is an implicit exit point. The method returns an incomplete `Task` to the caller when the first `await` of an incomplete `Task` is reached internally.

Comment: Got it. If I didn't want to it to be an async/await implementation, is it okay to return a Task.Run(() => *while loop code*) from `SpinUntilCancelled` ?

Comment: @TeeZadAwk yes, if you enclose the loop in a `Task.Run` then functionally will be OK. Using the async/await machinery is a bit more efficient though, because you'll avoid blocking a thread. 1 thread less = 1 MB smaller memory footprint for your app. Also if you port this code to a WinForms or WPF app, the code inside the loop of the async/await version will run in the UI thread, so you'll be able to interact with UI controls without having to resort to dispatcher invocations. This happens because the async/await machinery restores automatically the synchronization context after each `await`.

Comment: Don't you mean the code in the loop of the async/await version will NOT run in the UI thread, but that the captured context will be the UI thread, so the continuation will be on the UI thread?

Comment: @TeeZadAwk everything inside the `SpinUntilCancelled` that is runnable, will run in the UI thread. The awaiting of the `Task.Delay` is not runnable, because it is just an event handler attached to some internal timer, so for the most part no code is actually running. But when there is code running, it will be in the UI thread.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of Await/Async that you're not running on the UI thread so that the application is more responsive? :/

Comment: @TeeZadAwk yes, if you have a heavy computation to do, you should avoid doing it on the UI thread. But after the computation is done, it is generally desirable to return to the UI thread in order to update the UI with the results of the computation. In your case the asynchronous operation is not a computation, but just a delay. But even if it was a computation wrapped into an asynchronously implemented `Task`, nothing would change for the `SpinUntilCancelled`. Still everything runnable inside it would run on the UI thread, with the computational `Task` not counted as runnable but as awaitable.